# is it possible to open a popup with javascript and then detect when the user closes it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

The question is pretty much all in the title.

Is it possible (and how?) to open a popup with javascript and then detect when the user closes it?

I am using jquery within the project so a jquery solution would be good. Cheers!

Comment: define "pop-up". Are we talking some sort of on-page rendered modal box? A javascript alert? A new browser window?

Comment: A new browser window... sorry for my lack of clarity

Answer (score 112, accepted):

If you have control over the contents of the pop-up, handle the window's `unload` event there and notify the original window via the `opener` property, checking first whether the opener has been closed. Note this won't always work in Opera.

```
window.onunload = function() {
    var win = window.opener;
    if (!win.closed) {
        win.someFunctionToCallWhenPopUpCloses();
    }
};
```

Since the `unload` event will fire whenever the user navigates away from the page in the pop-up and not just when the window is closed, you should check that the pop-up has actually closed in `someFunctionToCallWhenPopUpCloses`:

```
var popUp = window.open("popup.html", "thePopUp", "");
function someFunctionToCallWhenPopUpCloses() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        if (popUp.closed) {
            alert("Pop-up definitely closed");
        }
    }, 1);
}
```

If you don't have control over the contents of the pop-up, or if one of your target browsers does not support the `unload` event, you're reduced to some kind of polling solution in the main window. Adjust interval to suit.

```
var win = window.open("popup.html", "thePopUp", "");
var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (win.closed !== false) { // !== is required for compatibility with Opera
        window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
        someFunctionToCallWhenPopUpCloses();
    }
}, 200);
```

Comment: I recommend the polling solution instead of the `unload` event since it is compatible with more browsers (see https://opera-bugs.jottit.com/).

Comment: @JonathonHill: Agreed. I alluded to the Opera problem earlier in the answer, but I should have made the point more clearly. Thanks for the edit. Btw, what's the reason for requiring `window.closed !== false` in Opera?

Comment: It is a workaround for a bug in Opera. I discovered it from https://opera-bugs.jottit.com/.

Comment: @JonathonHill: Yes, I read the page. I was hoping for more detail. Don't worry, I'll look it up.

Comment: 'closed' property is not a part of DOM specification.

Comment: @Shrike: No. I'm surprised it hasn't been standardized in HTML5 because it is implemented in all major browsers, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: In any case, if using the polling option, be absolutely sure not to forget the `window.clearInterval()` call. If it's not included, the original page will continue to poll... over and over and over...

Comment: @TimDown: this is realy working solution (I used pollTimer). How to implement it in "for" loop? I have the list of links and I need open every link in new window (with its own js) in "for" loop and wait until this new window will be closed and then continue loop

Comment: Found the way: jobTimerId = setTimeout(function run() {job(); jobTimerId = setTimeout(run, 100); }, 0);

Answer (score 15):

There is a very simple solution to your problem.

First make a new object which will open up a pop like this :

```
var winObj = window.open('http://www.google.com','google','width=800,height=600,status=0,toolbar=0');
```

In order to know when this popup window is closed, you just have to keep checking this with a loop like the following :

```
var loop = setInterval(function() {   
    if(winObj.closed) {  
        clearInterval(loop);  
        alert('closed');  
    }  
}, 1000);
```

Now you can replace alert with any javascript code you want.

Have Fun! :)

Comment: Note that Google sets the `cross-origin-opener-policy` header, so `winObj.closed` will return `true` even if the window is not closed.

Answer (score 9):

Try looking into the [`unload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload) and [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) window events. Monitoring these should give you an opportunity to call back when the DOM unloads when the window is closed via something like this:

```
var newWin = window.open('/some/url');
newWin.onunload = function(){
  // DOM unloaded, so the window is likely closed.
}
```

Comment: Thanks ajm looks great. Is there anyway to get the url of a popup by any chance?

Comment: This won't work cross browser. You need to handle the `unload` event in the pop-up.

Comment: Unload fires with every new request, not just when the window closes.

Comment: Yeah, YMMV with unload. Likely, you'll need a combination of unload and beforeunload to cover the IEs. @Josh - Unload should fire whenever the Document of the child window unloads from the browser independent of requests; what behavior are you seeing?

Comment: For instance, if there are hyperlinks within the popup window, clicking them will fire `unload`.

Comment: I get this event firing twice, once when the popup window opens, and once when it closes. The first time, `this` is about:blank, and the second time, `this` is the actual window object corresponding to the page. I am checking `this.url` for being undefined to work around this.

Answer (score 6):

If you can use the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), it actually has a `close` event.

Comment: jQuery isn't the solution to every problem :).

Comment: True, true. I should have begun my answer with the word "if" as in "If you can use the jQuery UI Dialog" and not just *assumed* it was possible. Hey! Wait a second...

Comment: And, when it comes to JavaScript, jQuery is never really a solution to problems, but is often a huge, HUGE, **HUGE** shortcut to the solution, whatever it may be. You learn more by taking the scenic route, but, in many cases, I and most people prefer the (huge, HUGE, **HUGE** ) jQuery shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

To open a new window call:

```
var wnd = window.open("file.html", "youruniqueid", "width=400, height=300");
```

If you just want to know when that window is going to close, use `onunload`.

```
wnd.onunload = function(){
    // do something
};
```

If you want a confirmation from the user before the can close it, use `onbeforeunload`.

```
wnd.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return "are you sure?";
};
```

Comment: This won't work cross browser. You need to handle the `unload` event in the pop-up document.

Comment: Unload fires with every new request, not just when the window closes.

Answer (score 3):

We do this in one of my projects at work.

The trick is to have a JS function in your parent page that you plan to call when the popup is closed, then hook the unload event in the popup.

The `window.opener` property refers to the page that spawned this popup.

For example, if I wrote a function named `callingPageFunction` on my original page, I would call it from the popup like this:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    window.opener.callingPageFunction()
});
```

Two notes:

1. This should be wrapped in a ready function.
2. I have an anonymous function because you may want other logic in there

Answer (score 2):

I thinks best way is:

```
const popup = this.window.open(url.toString());
popup.addEventListener('unload', ()=> console.log('closed'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, handle the onbeforeUnload event for the popup window and then call a function on the parent window using:

```
window.opener.myFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
onunload event will be triggered whenever DOM is unloaded for example if url is changed and previous page DOM is unloaded and DOM for new page is loaded.

```
var newWin = window.open('/some/url',"Example");
    
newWin.onunload = function(){
     if(newWin.closed){
       // DOM unloaded and Window Closed.Do what ever you want to do here
     } 
}
```