# Trigger event on a page when a popup window is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Page *x* creates a pop-up window (page *y*).  When page *y* is closed, I need an event to trigger on page *x*.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it possible to open a popup with javascript and then detect when the user closes it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291712/is-it-possible-to-open-a-popup-with-javascript-and-then-detect-when-the-user-clos)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the top.opener.document to access the page x from page y:

on page x:

```
function onTrigger()...
...
window.open(page_y,...)
```

on page y:

```
top.opener.document.onTrigger();
```

or

```
window.opener.document.onTrigger();
```

or even do:

```
top.opener.document.form1.input1.val="xxx";
```