# Loading pdf file in child window, why does ready work but no other events

Tags: jquery

I'm loading a .pdf file in a pop up window.  I want to attach an event.  The ready event works perfectly fine, but the other events do not.  Why is this?

This works:

```
var destURL = "c:\mypdf.pdf;
$(window.open(destURL)).ready(handler);
```

This does not:

```
var destURL = "c:\mypdf.pdf;
$(window.open(destURL)).unload(handler);
```

At first I was thinking you cannot add jquery to a page that is really just a pdf document, but the fact that .ready is working makes me think otherwise.  None of the other events work either, just .ready.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this is possible, at least not cross browser. In FF using pdf.js for example the unload handler is called, but immediately after the window loads.

[is it possible to open a popup with javascript and then detect when the user closes it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291712/is-it-possible-to-open-a-popup-with-javascript-and-then-detect-when-the-user-clo) has a useable answer using polling.