# Javascript/PHP: Open window to install twitter API then send back user info to main window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use window.open() to open a popup that will uses OAuth to redirect the user around and install my Twitter application, then closes itself.

Before closing itself however, I would like to send to the main window the username of the client. I tried `var win = window.opener;` followed by `win.someFunction(username);` but it is not working, I guess before the "opener" property is lost in the redirections that OAuth does.

Is there any way from the Child Window to find the Parent Window and send data? I checked and there is no `window.setName('parent');` and `getWindowByName('parent');` hehehe, that would be too good to be true.

**UPDATE:**

I am using 3-legged authorization

The thing I tried that I'm talking about in the second paragraph comes from this:
[is it possible to open a popup with javascript and then detect when the user closes it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291712/is-it-possible-to-open-a-popup-with-javascript-and-then-detect-when-the-user-clo)

Comment: Are you using the 3-legged authorization? (if not, which auth model are you using from [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens)?)

Comment: Yes I this is what I'm using!

Comment: Have you set a callback url?

Comment: Yes I did, and that callback url works, I can sent an alert('Bob') but sending data to caller window doesn't work (using chrome)

Comment: Not sure about twitter, but many api's that uses oauth with popup window allso uses window.postMessage. As popup is not with same origin with parent, so you cant access popup data. So you could try to set up listener to catch message.

Comment: Only works with iframes I think, not with popup windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well turns out I just put a time to detect when the window was closed then sent an AJAX request to get the data I needed.