# Get notified when location of opened popup window changed

Tags: javascript, html, oauth, popup, window.location

I'm implementing external OAuth authentication at my webiste.
On button click I'm opening popup with let's facebook auth page.
Now I need to know when authentication is completed to read an OAuth token and close the popup.

```
click: function () {
   var popup = window.open(url, title, '<options>');
   popup.onload = function () {
       //1. if url contains token - finish OAuth authentication
       //2. close popup

       //but 'onload' doesn't work for external domains
   }
   return false;
},
```

When I'm trying to access using polling technique I'm hetting the following security error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "https://some_app_host_not_the_same_as_following.com" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "https://some_auth_host_which_works_with_facebook.com". Protocols, domains,
>   and ports must match.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it possible to open a popup with javascript and then detect when the user closes it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291712/is-it-possible-to-open-a-popup-with-javascript-and-then-detect-when-the-user-clo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over the contents of the pop-up, handle the window's unload event there and notify the original window via the opener property, checking first whether the opener has been closed. Note this won't always work in Opera.

```
window.onunload = function() {
    var win = window.opener;
    if (win.closed) {
        win.someFunctionToCallWhenPopUpCloses();
    }
};
```

Since the unload event will fire whenever the user navigates away from the page in the pop-up and not just when the window is closed, you should check that the pop-up has actually closed in someFunctionToCallWhenPopUpCloses:

```
var popUp = window.open("popup.html", "thePopUp", "");
function someFunctionToCallWhenPopUpCloses() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        if (popUp.closed) {
            alert("Pop-up definitely closed");
        }
    }, 1);
}
```

If you don't have control over the contents of the pop-up, or if one of your target browsers does not support the unload event, you're reduced to some kind of polling solution in the main window. Adjust interval to suit.

```
var win = window.open("popup.html", "thePopUp", "");
var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (win.closed !== false) { // !== is required for compatibility with Opera
        window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
        someFunctionToCallWhenPopUpCloses();
    }
}, 200);
```

Comment: I already implemented polling solution and unfortunately was unable to read the location property of the opened popup. Access Denied error :/