# Display an Overlay on Parent Tab (page) until all its child tabs (pages) are opened

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Suppose I have Parent Page.

[image: Click]

When I click on Print a new tab (page) is opened for print preview.

What I want is when I click on print an overlay should be shown on parent tab (page) to stop further work until child tab is closed.

> Because when print tab (page) (child) is opened, most of the functions on
>   parent tab (page) are not working properly.

**Note: I am using Google Default print/preview functionality.**

I am not be able write the code to perform the above described scenario. How can I detect in parent page that its child page is closed?

Comment: Could you share some code? It sounds like you have already described the solution but are asking someone to write the code. I'm sure there are answers out there that will cover what you're asking.

Comment: Yes i need a code :( i don't know how to get the child tab to tell parent tab that `i am closing` ...

Comment: Could you share how you have the DOM setup?

Comment: I cant share that :(

Comment: `How can i detect in parent page that its child page is closed` By child page, do you mean browser print dialog? EDIT: ok i see, you open it in new tab BUT could you share this js code at least?!

Comment: its simple! `<a href='....' target='_blank'>Print</a>` when that page is reloaded `window.print()` is called.

Comment: So what about the [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3291931/2953335).

Comment: Yes that's the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dialog` in jQuery [follow this link to view](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) or you might use in your code like

```
var childNode= window.open('/uri of child');
```

then use

```
childNode.onunload = function(){  
// code after child closed
}
```

if not then you can also try

```
window.onunload = function() {if(!window.opener.closed && childNode.closed){
//code after child closed
}}
```